# Checkbox1 does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, list, configuration

Whats wrong with my checkbox1 name?

```
if (checkBox1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked) sb.AppendLine(@"\include{chapter2.tex}");
```

my other class line:

```
 config.Parts = new List<DocPart>();

                var part1 = new DocPart
                {
                    Title = "Second Chapter",
                    Checked = checkBox1.Checked
                };

                config.Parts.Add(part1);
```

And its says that chechBox1 does not exits in current context. Whats wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Where are those classes exactly?

Comment: Please show a bit more code to make us clear the scope of `chechBox1 `.

Comment: If your question has typos, your code may well have typos too.. (chechBox1  vs checkBox1 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8zbaa6f.aspx) says clearly about this error:

> This error frequently occurs if you declare a variable in a loop or a
>   try or if block and then attempt to access it from an enclosing code
>   block or a separate code block.

So you need to check the scope in which you have defined the `chechBox1`